# have to press F5 in order to call bean on fire-fox

Tags: java, jsp, firefox

I have encountered some wierd problem,
I have a button that its action is to call to some method of bean which forward me to other page,  but its's not working (it doesn't calls the method) unless i'm pressing F5 , but the problem exists only in fire-fox, for example in internet explorer its working greate, someone have any idea how to solve it?
thanks.

Comment: @skaffman/casperOne: how is this ambiguous? Pressing F5 solves the problem, so the cause seems obvious enough.

Answer (score 1):

You need to tell the browser to not cache dynamic JSP pages. You can achieve this by creating a `Filter` which is mapped on the desired URL pattern and does the following in `doFilter()` method:

```
@Override
public void doFilter(ServletRequest req, ServletResponse res, FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
    HttpServletResponse response = (HttpServletResponse) res;
    response.setHeader("Cache-Control", "no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate"); // HTTP 1.1.
    response.setHeader("Pragma", "no-cache"); // HTTP 1.0.
    response.setDateHeader("Expires", 0); // Proxies.
    chain.doFilter(req, res);
}
```